# Marketing Cloud - Data Load of 23 Million into All Subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-import

We have a requirement where by we need to load 26 M records of subscribers into Marketing cloud.

Currently only way to do this is to put the details in  file and by using enhancedFTP load into the All Subscribers list or direct import.

But when it comes to very large volumes whats a better way to do it? We can use API's to make call out from Marketing Cloud to get information from 3rd party system.

Please let me know if anybody has handled similar large data loads.

Do we have tools like data loader that can be used with Marketing Cloud?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no external tool like data loader in marketing cloud to upload data directly into your lists or data extensions.
As for now these are the only two options which you are already aware of.

Enhanced FTP if file size is more than 20 MB and using API calls.